# Geração de código intermediário - Recursão na verificação

Tags: python, compiladores

Boa tarde, galera. Eu estou em uma etapa da matéria de compiladores que é a geração de código intermediário da minha gramática. Após as etapas de análise léxica, sintática, semântica.

Basicamente eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
from infixToPostfix import infixToPostfix # Importação da função que faz a conversão de infixa pra posfixa

def verAtribuicao(variavel, i, cod, tok):
    ex = ''
    while tok[i][1] != 'fim_linha':  # Enquanto não encontrar um token de fim linha
        ex += ' ' + tok[i][0]  # o buffer acumula os tokens encontrados
        i += 1
    return tac(variavel, infixToPostfix(ex), cod, i)  # Chama a função tac (three address code) passando a variavel, expressao pos fixada, a lista e a iteração

def tac(var, expression, cod, it):
    exp = expression.split()
    stack = []
    oper = ['+', '-', '*', '/']
    for i in range(len(exp)):
        if exp[i] in oper:
            v1 = stack.pop()
            v2 = stack.pop()
            t = f'{v2} {exp[i]} {v1}'
            if len(exp) == i+1:
                cod.append(f'{var} := {t}')
            else:
                cod.append(f'_t{it} := {t}')
                stack.append(f'_t{it}')
                it += 1
        else:
            stack.append(exp[i])
    if len(stack) == 1:
        cod.append(f'{var} := {stack[0]}')

# Abertura da lista de tokens retornada na análise léxica

with open("lista_tokens.txt", "r") as arquivo:
    tk = arquivo.readlines()

# variáveis de controle

i = 0
ctrl = 0

# declaração das listas de apoio

cod_intermediario = []
registro_log = []
tokens = []

# Loop apenas pra inserir as informações das linhas já delimitado

for j in tk:
    tokens.append(j.split('|'))

# Faz a verificação da declaração das variáveis

for tk in tokens:
    if tk[1] == 'id' and tokens[ctrl-1][1] == 'tiponum':
        cod_intermediario.append(f'INTEIRO {tk[0]}')
        registro_log.append(f'Declaração da variável {tk[0]}')
    ctrl += 1

def verifica(tokens, i, L, C): # Função para fazer a verificação de leitura, escrita e atribuição
    expressao = ''
    if tokens[i][1] == 'ler':  # Verifica se o token é de leitura, mostra o token e pula 4 iterações
        cod_intermediario.append(f'LEIA {tokens[i+2][0]}')
        registro_log.append(f'Reconhecido comando leitura da variável {tokens[i+2][0]}')
        i += 4
    elif tokens[i][1] == 'escrever':  # Verifica se o token é de escrita, mostra o token e pula 4 iterações
        cod_intermediario.append(f'ESCREVA {tokens[i+2][0]}')
        registro_log.append(f'Reconhecido comando de escrita')
        i += 4
    elif tokens[i][1] == 'atribuicao':  # Verifica se o token é de atribuição e avança 1 iteração
        variavel = tokens[i - 1][0]
        i += 1
        registro_log.append(f'Reconhecido expressão atribuída para {tokens[i-2][0]}')
        verAtribuicao(variavel, i, cod_intermediario, tokens)
    elif tokens[i][1] == 'enquanto': # Verifica se o token encontrado é um enquanto
        i += 2
        while tokens[i][1] != 'parenteses_fecha': # enquanto não encontrar um fechamento de parenteses, acumula os tokens no buffer
            expressao += ' ' + tokens[i][0]
            i += 1
        if expressao.split()[1] == '<=':
            operador = '>'
        elif expressao.split()[1] == '>=':
            operador = '<'
        elif expressao.split()[1] == '==':
            operador = '='
        cod_intermediario.append(f'_L{L}: if {expressao.split()[0]} {operador} {expressao.split()[2]} goto _L{L+1}')
        i += 2
        i = verifica(tokens, i, L+1, C)
        cod_intermediario.append(f'_L{L+1}:')
        registro_log.append(f'Reconhecido expressão enquanto para {expressao}')
    elif tokens[i][1] == 'se': # Verifica se o token encontrado é um enquanto
        i += 2
        while tokens[i][1] != 'parenteses_fecha': # enquanto não encontrar um fechamento de parenteses, acumula os tokens no buffer
            expressao += ' ' + tokens[i][0]
            i += 1
        if expressao.split()[1] == '<=':
            operador = '>'
        elif expressao.split()[1] == '>=':
            operador = '<'
        elif expressao.split()[1] == '==':
            operador = '='
        cod_intermediario.append(f'_C{C}: if {expressao.split()[0]} {operador} {expressao.split()[2]} goto _C{C+1}')
        i += 2
        cod_intermediario.append(f'_C{C+1}:')
        registro_log.append(f'Reconhecido expressão se para {expressao}')
    return i

L = C = 0

while i < len(tokens):
    i = verifica(tokens, i, L, C)
    i += 1

for t in registro_log:
    print(t)

print('\n')
print('*' * 50)
print('\n')

for j in cod_intermediario:
    print(j)
```

Dentro da função verifica eu tenho duas condições: Quando é encontrado um "enquanto", e quando é encontrado um "se".

Digamos que na minha gramática abaixo:

```
run

integer f = 1;
integer i = 1;
integer n;

display("Digite qual numero deseja calcular a fatorial");
input(n);
while(i <= n){
    f = f * i;
    i = i+1;
}
exit
```

Como eu tenho um while e dentro desse while eu tenho duas linhas de atribuições, até aí tudo bem... mas por exemplo, pode acontecer de dentro dele ter um if, ou outro while, etc. Alguém consegue me ajudar a ter uma ideia do que fazer nesse caso? Obrigado!